# Appending code to the_content

Tags: the-content

I'm trying to append some php code to `the_content` in a custom loop. I do not want to add a function because I only want to append the code to one instance of `the_content`, not throughout the whole site.

I'm using the [Read More Right Here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/read-more-right-here/) plugin to enable viewers to read a whole post (after clicking the more tag) that displays on the page (without going to single post). And I'm using the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin to output some content (when a check box is ticked in the back end) that I want to display at the end of each post. If I place my code to output the check box data AFTER `the_content` in my template, the info is displayed underneath the more tag. My aim is to append this to the bottom of `the_content` so that it is hidden (along with the rest of the post after the more tag) until you click 'read more' (and the rest of the post is revealed).

The code I am trying to append to the end of `the_content` is:

```
<?php
if( in_array( 'frazer-barton', get_field('who_specialises') ) )
{
echo '<img src="http://andersonlloyd.php.wired.co.nz/wp-content/themes/all/images/example-thumb.jpg" />';
}
if( in_array( 'sarah-simmers', get_field('who_specialises') ) )
{
echo '<img src="http://andersonlloyd.php.wired.co.nz/wp-content/themes/all/image/example2-thumb.jpg" />';
}
else {
echo '';
}
?>
```

I am not a PHP developer so any help on this is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to [filter `the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).

In your theme's *functions.php* or in a plugin:

```
function wpse74288_content_filter( $content ) {
    /* save field into variable, such as to call get_field only once
     * not required, but more efficient */
    $who_specialises = get_field('who_specialises');
    /* append to content on condition */
    if ( in_array( 'frazer-barton', $who_specialises ) ) {
        /* use correct img src attributes, shortened only for representation here */
        $content .= '<img src="http://andersonlloyd...images/example-thumb.jpg" />';
    } elseif ( in_array( 'sarah-simmers', $who_specialises ) ) {
        $content .= '<img src="http://andersonlloyd.../images/example2-thumb.jpg" />';
    }
    /* return the content, whether appending happened or not */
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse74288_content_filter' );
```

As an aside, this question is probably the dupe of a dupe of a dupe [+ n dupes], had you known what to search for.